# Anybody using kriging for surface interpolation from huge point datasets?

Tags: interpolation

Is anybody here using kriging for surface interpolation from huge datasets (> 1 million points)?
How large datasets are your datasets and what do you model?
Also what software are you using?

Comment: Poll questions are not a good fit for the StackExchange model, see http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. Presumably, you are not asking this question out of idle curiosity -- if you edit your question to make clear what you are expecting from an answer, you are much more likely to get a useful response.